# Can be replaced with method reference using reflection in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, reflection, java-8, method-reference

I have this code in intellij:

```
 return collection.stream().anyMatch(annotation -> 
                        method.isAnnotationPresent(annotation));
```

And the compiler tells me that "method.isAnnotationPresent(annotation)" can be replaced with method reference and I can't figure out how to do it because it has an argument.

Does anyone know how to make that?

Comment: If IntelliJ tells you that this can be converted, just tell IntelliJ to do the conversion…

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can replace your code to use the method reference (look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)) as shown below:

```
return collection.stream().anyMatch(method::isAnnotationPresent);
```

Basically, you are providing the `isAnnotationPresent()` **method** **definition** to the **Lambda expression** (of `anyMatch` method which accepts for [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html)) and the value from the stream will automatically be passed as an argument to the `anyMatch` method.

Comment: you are right! I did it a lot of times, maybe because I'm using reflection I couldn't think it like always. Thank you!

Comment: I could't try it yet because it still building and now I have to find out how to solve another problem, but I replaced the lambda expression with your definition and it compiles perfectly.

Comment: yes! sorry for that, I don't post here very often and I'm not used to doing that. I've just done it!